# asp.net + c# tips to edit docx inside my app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open/handle Word documents like SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907960/open-handle-word-documents-like-sharepoint)

I´ve developed one website where it is possible to upload docx files to it. Now I want a way to edit it directly in browser, I meant, a way to do like google docs does.

OR

Copy from MSWord to my app window e maintain all the formats, including tables.

Comment: Check [Editing Microsoft Word documents in ASP.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1907960/55209) and [Open/handle Word documents like SharePoint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3225414/55209)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the manipulation of word documents you can use [**DocX**](http://docx.codeplex.com/). With this you can read/write from/to word documents (docx not doc). This however is a long way from editing your document in a google docs like manner...

It does match your second request though!